# For loop on test case titles in robot frame work

Tags: selenium, automation, robotframework

On one page there are various item. I am able to iterate over all items/elements on the page.

Though would like to keep every iteration is a separate test cases.

As in below Test case title First Page  Item No   expand

Is there any way to put test case name  in for loop.
For example First Page and Item No both can be variable and controlled by for loop.

```
*** Test Cases ***
First Page  Item No   expand 
     : FOR    ${INDEX}    IN RANGE    1    80
     \    Click Element    xpath=/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[${INDEX}]/div[1]/div/p[2]
```

Comment: You should create a keywords and then you set condition IF ELSE for call those keyword

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding this should not be possible. However there are two ways to get around:

1. Treat is as one test case, have a keyword that does the FOR loop
2. Have 80 test cases calling one keyword with an ${index} attribute